# Car AC temperature setting

Tags: ac, suzuki

Since I live in India, and ambient temperature always around 30°C; I always keep the AC running at 24°C in Auto mode in my 2016 Suzuki Baleno.

But recently my AC compressor clutch got damaged, and the mechanic told me that it’s because of setting the temperature at 24. Instead I should have kept it running at lowest temperature always. Is it right?

Comment: When ac is used, do you feel the engine load and unload as indication of the ac compressor cycling on and off repeatedly or does it remain on? Some vehicles cycle compressors while others run without cycling. A cycling compressor may wear out prematurely depending on frequency of cycles while always on won't.

Comment: @FDryer , I usually switch on AC after running for few minutes with windows rolled down. And while switching it on for the first time, I noticed the engine load. But nothing after that.

Comment: If using ac doesn't feel like repeated changes in engine loading/unloading while driving, then I presume your ac compressor is always running. Improved designs like variable displacement compressors (VDC) allow small engines to run constantly without the old style compressors cycling on and off, loading and unloading the engine. This translates to a push/pull feeling in a vehicle. Unfortunately, without more info, no one can say what failed as most repair shops mask their repairs in a veil of secrecy to vehicle owners unfamiliar with ac systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer should be no, he is not correct, since the AC compressor is designed to be turned on and off using the clutch.

In countries with a lower ambient temperature the clutch may well be cycling even more often than yours does.

It also depends how it failed, did the electric magnetic coil break?  Did the clutch friction components wear?  Did the bearing fail?   Different failure modes may be more likely under different usage patterns.

Sometimes component just don’t last as long as other identical components and it is nothing to do with how you used it.

Comment: Don’t know what actually failed. They just told the clutch is having trouble rotating smoothly. Hence cooling will be affected.